# What is the best way to create a PHP/MySQL upgrade script for a software developer?

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade

I am a PHP software developer and am looking for the best solution to get around this concern I have.  I am create a script that will in the future have new releases that includes new features, bugfixes, etc.  I know how to do the code changes in the upgrade script, however I the script I am developing uses MySQL to store data in multiple tables.

**Now here is the question, I have figured out how to make an install script for the initial release, however what is the best solution/method to making an upgrade script that can upgrade any previous version up to the latest version?  The latest version has new MySQL tables (not a problem), however it also changes the database structure (new columns, delete columns, etc.)  I will create a scenario below to better picture what I am worried about.**

> v0.1.0 - Initial Release
>
> v0.1.1 - Has a new database table and some fields added to the table structure
>
> v0.2.0 - Has more new fields added to different tables
>
> My concern is the the upgrade v0.1.0 > v0.2.0 because there were changes between the two versions.

**UPDATE** I probably could have mentioned that I am using GitHub as my VCS for the code alone.  All code changes are saved there and in the install or upgrade script for code changes, I just plan on overwriting the user's current files as they shouldn't have any data within class/function files.

Comment: How are you getting the correct version number?

Comment: Because the code is so early in development it can be changed, however I am currently just defining a constant like below:

define('SCRIPT_VERSION', '0.1.0');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, the best approach is to create a versioning table in MySQL that includes the application's version number along with any queries that change the structure of the database. So essentially:

```
CREATE TABLE versions (
    app_version DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    query TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
);
```

With our install script, we take note of our initial application version and our destination application version and select all queries that need to be executed for this to work.

```
SELECT query FROM versions WHERE app_version > {$initialAppVersion} AND app_version <= {$destinationAppVersion} ORDER BY created ASC;
```

In PHP:

```
foreach ($resultset AS $row) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($row['query']);
    try {
       $stmt->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) { /* handle exception */ }
}
```

Comment: Nice way, except catching an exception and silently stifle it :-/

Comment: What's wrong with letting the OP decide how to handle exceptions? I just didn't want to hard-code anything in there.

Comment: Whatever you write, the OP will decide how to handle the exceptions. But for a beginner reading your answer, at least writing `catch (Exception $e) { /* handle exception */ }` could be nicer than just `catch (Exception $e) {}` for avoiding a bad practice. Just a suggestion.

Comment: To be honest, I have never actually used exceptions within my PHP code.  Before I used this, I would definitely have to look a little more in to how those work.

I like this suggestion though as I can create my own upgrade script.

Comment: @Frosty: that's a good point. Mending my example. +1 for you.

Comment: @Brandon: you don't have to handle the exception in that way, either. The example uses PDO instead of the mysql built-in functions, but no matter what you use, you're basically just checking to make sure the query executed properly and if it didn't, you probably want to stop script execution.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current schema version they are on somewhere.

For the upgrade script have it check to make sure it's on the previous version before it continues making any updates.  This will prevent updates from being skipped or missed.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

Some ORMs like **Propel** and **Doctrine** allow to create automatically such migration scripts.

Check for example:

- http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/WhatsNew#Migrations
- http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/new-to-migrations-in-1-1